# AndroidアプリのWebViewで読み込んだWebページのスクロール速度を上げたいです。

Tags: android, webview

現在、Androidアプリの開発をしております。
WebViewを使ってスマホ版のwebページを表示させているのですが、
読み込んだWebページをスクロールする際にカクついてしまいます。

ネットで「android:hardwareAccelerated="true"」にすると改善されるという記事を見つけ、
試してみたのですが、まだ少しスクロールでカクついてしまいます。

他に何か対策方法はあるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

ちゃんとHardwareRendererになっているのであればWebViewの描画そのものが原因でスクロールでカクツクということは(理論上)ありません。

何故ならばWebViewの仕組みは
・GPU(HWRender)でタイルをスクロール、拡大、縮小等
・Skiaにてタイルの中身を描画
となっているので、ページの中身が表示されないことはあってもタイルのスクロールは中身の表示の有無には無関係だからです。

ですので、スクロールがカクツク原因は
1. UIスレッドで何かカクツク様な処理が行われている
2. その他CPU専有処理が起こっている
3. (最近はほぼないが)SuraceFlinger以下の処理が追いついていない
4. (状況による)GPUの処理が追いついていない
etc...等です。

3.4.はまぁ無視して良いです。
3.はsystraceで解析可能ですが、これが原因ならばアプリ側からは解決不可能です。
4.はAdreno Profiler等で解析可能ですが、激しいGPU処理を行なっていないならこれも原因ではないでしょう。

1.はtraceviewやsystraceで解析可能です。
2.はtopコマンドやsystraceで解析可能です。

どちらのツールも公式サイトに解析方法が記載されています。
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html

ちなみに開発をEmulatorで行われている場合、
製品にはGMSのChromeが搭載されておりWebViewもChrome内部のものを使用しますが
EmulatorではAOSPのWebViewが使われるはずなので挙動が多少変わってくると思います。